# Perl script process input file and achieve desire output

Tags: perl

This is Perl script, reads file that contains IP and stsco names. I spilt items to two columns and use the second c2 to be processed. And calling another Perl script to return the values I need and print it out in a file.
If you see my input file line 8 ( 10.22.1.50            stsco25527020 ) doesn't take this value not sure why, maybe because there is white spaces between IP and stsco.
could you please help me on how to achieve the desire output? and also appreciated if you know why my script is not taking value in line 8

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $input_file = 'status.txt';
my $output_file = 'status_results.txt';
open my $fh, '<', $input_file or die $!;
open my $wfh, '>', $output_file or die $!;

while (<$fh>){
    chomp;
    next if /^\</;
    next if /^\s*$/;

    my ($c1, $c2) = split /\s/, $_;
    my $stssysId = "$c2";
    $stssysId = `/bin/call_api.pl --op=stssys_id --kv stssys_id=$stssysId | grep Status`;
    print $wfh "$c2\t$stssysId\n";
}
```

status.txt ( This is input file )

```
10.22.10.12   stsco28698039
10.22.13.38   stsco28016005
10.22.11.23   stsco28497006
10.22.10.15   stsco28598003
10.22.18.12   stsco28534122
10.22.10.15   stsco28598002
10.22.12.10   stsco26944008
10.22.1.50            stsco25527020
10.22.70.21   stsco28698022
10.22.15.22   stsco28698024
10.24.70.74   stsco9372006
10.24.54.16   stsco28698020
```

status_results ( output file )

```
stsco28698039         "Status" : "Active",

stsco28016005         "Status" : "Active",

stsco28497006         "Status" : "Active",

stsco28598003         "Status" : "Active",

stsco28534122         "Status" : "Active",

stsco28598002         "Status" : "Active",

stsco26944008         "Status" : "Active",


stsco28698022
stsco28698024
stsco9372006
stsco28698020
stsco28598004         "Status" : "Active",
```

Desire output - or results - (I want to remove "status" : " and ')

```
stsco28698039         Active

stsco28016005         Active

stsco28497006         Active

stsco28598003         Active

stsco28534122         Active

stsco28598002         Active

stsco26944008         Active


stsco28698022
stsco28698024
stsco9372006
stsco28698020
stsco28598004         Active
```

Comment: Note that the status_results.txt output file the value stsco28698022, stsco28698024, stsco9372006, stsco28698020 are empty because no value to be returned

Comment: I don't know what most of this script is doing, but that shell command is setting off every red flag in my brain at once. You're interpolating a Perl variable into a shell instruction with no escaping, no checks, no sanitizing, nothing. Even an accidental single quote or parenthesis in your input will nuke this script from orbit, let alone a malicious input file.

Comment: Hi @SilvioMayolo Thanks for your reply, I'm looping through an input file and querying each single stsco ID to check the status of provisioning is active. exactly like an output file above. I call an api script to tells me if the status is active

Comment: @Ayad We never know what the API script does. We have to substitute(using regex) the value `"Status" :` in the variable `$stssysId` once you run the API script and print the result to get desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try splitting on one or more whitespace characters instead of a single whitespace character:

```perl
my ($c1, $c2) = split /\s+/, $_;
```

To make `$stsysId` have only the Active part:

```
#Matches any of the characters '"', ",", ":", space, or the word Status
$stsysId =~ s/[",: ]|Status//g;
```

or

```
#[0] is "" (the empty string), [1] is Status, [2] is " : ", [3] is "Active"
$stsysId = (split '"', $stsysId)[3];
$stsysId //= ""; #Perl 5.10.0+
$stsysId = "" unless defined $stsysId; #older perls
```

or

```
#Match two double quote delimited strings, possibly with characters in between.
$stsysId =~ m/"([^"]+)".*?"([^"]+)"/;
$stsysId = $2 if defined $2;
```

Comment: Hi @Nathan Mills, many thanks! I tried your command with "+" and it works, my scripts takes the value in line 8 - second part now is resolved, now I'm trying to achieve the desired output

Comment: Excellent, many thanks it works. I have achieved the desired output
I added as per your answer $stsysId =~ s/[",: ]|Status//g; and it works

Answer (score 1):

Please investigate the following code snippet for compliance with your task.

More precise regular expression can be utilized to process input data to filter out desired input data. By doing so the code becomes shorter and more *error resistant*. Feel free to experiment with *regex* to match content of your input file.

In this particular case [split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split) without arguments (special case equivalence to **/\s+/**) will do what you desire -- split a string in two values. It is better to assign more appropriate names to the values as *ip* and *node*.

Usage of backticks to obtain status perhaps is not best option (although it does what you want). You could filter out undesirable parameters with external program in the pipe or use backticks in [list context](https://perlmaven.com/qx).

Perl provides `qx(command argument .. argument)` as alternative to backticks what makes code easier to read. Don't be shy to try use this option. [perl qx](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_qx.htm)

Instead you can use [open on a pipe](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut#Opening-a-pipe-for-reading) to the command which provides status of the node. This would allow you read command's output as a file and filter/capture information of interest with perl's instructions.

Or as alternative option you could use `system` call of command with an array of arguments (more secure form of call).

In provided code sample `$state` of the node is captured through regular expression for simplicity. By design it should capture state of the node - due absence of the **call_api.pl** utility this part wasn't tested.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $re = /\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\s+stsco\d+/;

while( <> ) {
    next unless /$re/;
    my($ip,$node) = split;
    my $status = `/bin/call_api.pl .....`;
    my($state) = $status =~ /^$node\s+"Status" : "(\w+)"/;
    say  join("\t",$node,$state);
}
```

Run as `script.pl nodes.txt > status.txt`

Reference:
[split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split),
[regex](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre),
[system](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system),
[qx](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_qx.htm),
[open](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut)
[null filehandle <>](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop)

Comment: this is very useful I will try it out

Answer (score 0):

After you have your script call the second script modify the string to remove the undesired portion:

```
  $stssysId =~ s/Status : //;
  $stssysId =~ s/\"//g;
```